# Grails UrlMapping Redirect to keep DRY

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am working with `Grails 2.1.1` and would like to add a handful of customized URLs that map to Controller Actions.

I can do that, but the original mapping still works.

For example, I created a mapping `add-property-to-directory` in my `UrlMappings` as follows:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/add-property-to-directory"(controller: "property", action: "create")
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Now, I can hit `/mysite/add-property-to-directory` and it will execute `PropertyController.create`, as I would expect.

However, I can still hit `/mysite/property/create`, and it will execute the same `PropertyController.create` method.

In the spirit of DRY, I would like to do a 301 Redirect from `/mysite/property/create` to `/mysite/add-property-to-directory`.

I could not find a way to do this in `UrlMappings.groovy`.  Does anyone know of a way I can accomplish this in Grails?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution that I implemented, based on Tom's answer:

**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/add-property-to-directory"(controller: "property", action: "create")
        "/property/create" {
            controller = "redirect"
            destination = "/add-property-to-directory"
        }


        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

**RedirectController.groovy**

```
class RedirectController {

    def index() {
        redirect(url: params.destination, permanent: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not possible as of now. There's a feature request for making it possible to specify redirects in url mappings - See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5994

Comment: @sudhir Thank you, that answers my question.  Could you please copy your comment to an Answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @sudhir, thanks for your comment and the useful link ... Tom edited his Answer and it led me on the right track to do what  was looking for so I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?" (
    controller: 'myRedirectControlller', action: 'myRedirectAction', params:[ controller: $controller, action: $action, id: $id ]
)

"/user/list" ( controller:'user', action:'list' )
```

and in the action you get the values normallny in params:

```
log.trace 'myRedirectController.myRedirectAction: ' + params.controller + ', ' + params.action + ', ' + params.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot change the main mapping to a redirect controller because I have other Controllers that do follow the Grails convention of `controller/action/id`.  I was hoping to be able to do explicit Redirects.

Comment: If you have only small ammount of controller with standard mapping, you can prepare additional specific rules. I have updated my comment to include one.

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  I accepted your answer, it led me on the right path.  I actually ended up creating the `RedirectController`, but instead of mapping `/$controller/$action?/$id?" to it, I created an entry for `property/create` to it, and will do so for each URL that I do not want repeated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but honestly I don't fully understand your final solution. You have more "patterns" mapped to the RedirectController?

Comment: Good point ... I edited my original question with the implemented solution.  Please see **Updated** section.

Answer (score 2):

As of Grails 2.3, it is possible to do redirects directly in the UrlMappings, without the need for a redirect controller. So in case you ever upgrade, you can redirect in UrlMappings like so, as per the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectMappings):

```
"/property/create"(redirect: '/add-property-to-directory')
```

Request parameters that were part of the original request will be included in the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

In recent Grails version (currently 5.x) you need to pass a `Map` into the `redirect:` property:

```
"/viewBooks"(redirect: [uri: '/add-property-to-directory'])
```

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#redirectMappings